# How to create auto generated membership id in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to create an auto-generated membership id of a user in the profile table based on the current date and username. User table has `OneToOneField` relationship with the profile table. So when I create a user, I have to put `username` in the registration form. The `signals.py` creates a profile row in the table for the user. I want when the profile is created it would have a membership id which is the mix of current date and username. My code is as follow:

**singlas.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from .models import Ext_User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=Ext_User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(Ext_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=False)
    membership_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I have got some guideline to user pre_save into `signals.py` but don't understand how to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ext_User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
       profile = Profile()
       profile.membership_id = str(instance.username) + str(datetime.datetime.now())
       profile.user_id = instance.pk
       profile.save()
```

format DateTime as your desired format